# How do I enable the middle mouse button for Pharo on Ubuntu?

Tags: pharo

I'm fairly new to Pharo. I'm running Ubuntu Raring Ringtail (13.04) and using the PPA recommended on the Pharo web site, together with the Pharo 30218 image, and looking to enable the middle-click capability. (I have a Logitech trackball, and several apps are already aware enough to use the scrolling capability of the middle wheel. So, I think it's something I need to do specifically for Pharo.)

Comment: Where and how do you want to use the middle mouse button? You might want to use `MouseEvent >> #blueButtonPressed`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mac so my answer may not be that useful for you. But the middle mouse button does not bring any menu in Pharo and by default the mouse wheel should work. Pay attention Pharo 3.0 is under heavy development, so to get started I would use Pharo 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Squeak image with your VM? There, middle/right mouse buttons are mapped to halo/context menu. If it works in Squeak, then the problem is with the Pharo image. If it does not work in Squeak either, the problem is with the VM.

You can get a current Squeak release here:
http://ftp.squeak.org/4.4/Squeak4.4-12327.zip plus
http://ftp.squeak.org/4.4/SqueakV41.sources.zip

Answer (score 0):

For me the key combination (modifier) I had to use to get the halos was: `alt+shift` and then click with `left mouse button`.