# Pharo image does not recognize middle mouse click on Debian

Tags: pharo

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17280577/52310) question, which was never really answered...

I'm running Debian Testing on a Lenovo Thinkpad T530.

I downloaded Pharo using the zeroconf script. About says

```
Pharo3.0
Latest update: #30860
```

I noticed that middle click didn't bring up the morphic halo as I expected, based on the description in *Pharo by Example*, nor did it do anything as far as I could tell.

I ran the Pharo VM with a Squeak image (as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303018/52310) answer), and middle mouse did exactly what I would have expected.

I couldn't find any more information about this, so I'm asking here.

Is there a way to enable the middle mouse? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Try shift + middle click.

(I'm using Debian Testing on T520)

Comment: That works; I'm more convinced that it's a bug now, though. According to `Sensor mouseButtons`, both middle-click and shift+middle-click count as a yellow button press (as does alt+shift+left-click), but middle-click doesn't bring up the halo.

Comment: Maybe because in linux middle click alone means something else - pasting selection? Even though this doesn't work there may be some kind of conflict or something.